# overflow-x:hidden doesn't work

Tags: css, web

I am working on a website where I want to disable horizontal scrolling but do allow vertical scrolling. So I did the following

```
<body style="overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">
```

Although I don't see any scrollbars, I am able to scroll (using touch pad on Mac). However, when I set

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
```

it disables all scrolling as I'd expect.

Any ideas how I can disable one way scrolling while enabling the other direction?

The website can be found on
[www.aeccons.com](http://www.aeccons.com)